# Reason for the slow soft keyboard input in android

Tags: android, performance, android-softkeyboard

I had implemented one application in which lots of forms are there.
The forms contain EditText box.
When I am trying to type in that text box using soft keyboard the response is too slow.
If I am making a new activity and using a layout only with the edittext box then its responds as soon as I tap on any character.

So what can be the reasons for slow response in edittext box typing?

Thanks,
bskania.

Comment: are u adding textWatcher on any of EditText, b'coz that will cause slow performance as per your code inside textChange...

Comment: No I had only assigned typeface to my edittext box. nothing else.

Comment: Is the parent of the EditText a ScrollView?

Comment: I don't think a parent `ScrollView` will cause slow performance...

Comment: check your performance on real device...

Comment: I KNOW it will cause slow performance. The reason is that every time you input a character with your keyboard, the whole scroll view has to get remeasured (several times, at that). Extend the ScrollView so you can put a log in onMeasure to see how much time it takes and how often it gets called.

Comment: Run the `DDMS Method Profiler` on your app while typing and then you can graphically see what is causing the slow down.

Comment: Are you doing some heavy operation on UI thread on edittext focus listener ?

Comment: yes I am having it in relative layout. and scrollview is parent of relative layout. But When I had used it in another application in the same way its working is not slow. I am testing it on real device only.

Comment: if I set a edittext in a custom view then its slow down the performance then what can be the way to resolve it? When I write a single character then its responds to slow and on measure method called each and every time I am typing.

Comment: Yes am using scroll view as a parent, its lagging can you please suggest some solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try making activity on ActivityManifest;

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard response is slow to various reasons.
I too faced this situation, In my case, there was a lot of images and tabs in the neighboring tabLayout , which was causing the issue.

I just hide (Visibility.GONE) the layout where there are a lot of bitmaps and all when I switched into the tab where there is editText. And added this line into manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

it resolved my issue.